# Why doesn't my icon appear on the desktop or task bar?

Tags: vb.net, icons, desktop, taskbar

My icon "Upload.ico" appears in the title bar of my VB form.
But it does not appear on the Windows desktop or Windows task bar.

[image: My icons]

Answer (score 1):

You must set the icon in your Application settings. Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, Properties, then in Application, set the icon:

[image]